# IF and REGEXMATCH formula excluding RR in a column but select for letters K-Z

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

So, I have a formula graciously shared by someone here that works amazing in highlighting cells in a column that contains letters from K to Z, excluding RR. Here it is below...

```
=REGEXMATCH(E5:E,"[K-Z]")*(REGEXMATCH(E5:E,"RR")=FALSE)
```

But, I'm trying to accomplish the same thing with an IF formula (not conditional formatting), where if a cell in column E contains a letter from K-Z, it will display the green checkbox, and if not, display the red down arrow. I'm not sure exactly how to exclude RR again in the equation. Here's the formula I'm trying to get to work...

```
={"OL";ARRAYFORMULA(IF(E5:E="",,if(REGEXMATCH(E5:E,"K|L|M|N|O|P|Q|R|S|T|U|V|W|X|Y|Z"),"✅","")))}
```

The formula works except it includes cells containing RR, I guess because R is in there? But I want to exclude cells containing RR.

Here's a [**Google Sheet**](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1pxlgfRqnNNO0drLqHOYA1_9EyhFmWIGlwaO56Pb1kng/edit?usp=sharing) that contains the formula I'm currently using.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I left a new sheet ("Erik Help") with a formula in B1 that somewhat follows the form of your original formula there, since that seems to be something you understand. All I did was add another outer `IF` to rule out instances of "RR" up front:

`={"OL";ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A2:A="",,IF(A2:A="RR","",IF(REGEXMATCH(A2:A,"[K-Z]"),"✅",""))))}`

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
={"OL"; INDEX(IF(
 REGEXMATCH(E5:E,"[K-Z]")*(REGEXMATCH(E5:E,"RR")=FALSE), 
 "✅", ""))}
```